# Memory leaks in iphone App

Tags: iphone, xcode, memory-leaks

Am all most done with my App.When am running the App on Simulator it works fine but when i run on the device for some time the debugger showing a message as "Program received signal 0".I tested the app with the help of instruments leaks it showing leaks.But am unable to figure out exactly where was the leak.Am releasing every object which am allocating.
For example am providing little part of my code:

```
     if([UIImagePickerController    isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary])
  {
    UIImagePickerController *picker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate=self;
    picker.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;        
   [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
   [picker release];
//  NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [[NSFileHandle alloc]initWithFileDescript
   }
```

In the above code leaks are showing at the UIImagePickerController *picker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]; but am releasing it.
Can some one provide me the detail information abt the leaks and how to fix them .Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In this line of code:

```
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

**self** (the parent controller) is actually retaining your picker and won't release it until the parent controller explicitly dismisses it. As long as your parent controller are dismissing this picker at some point in your code you'll be fine.

Comment: Sorry i donno whether i understood your ans correctly or not.Yeah am dismissing the picker in a delegate method.Still same problem:(